# Selling Musical Instruments and Comic Books

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

Assalamu Alaikum to My Brothers in Islam,

Can a Muslim who unfortunately in his Jahaliyyah  past owned Musical instruments and comic books, sell them now in order to use whatever money gained from that to donate it to needy Muslim brothers, without expecting any reward whatsoever from Allah Swt. 
OR 
Should he just dump them in the thrash because it's not permissible to sell such items?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to know that anything that is considered as haram, is also haram to be sold or more exactly is considered a haram income.

> I saw the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) sitting neat the Black stone (or at a corner of the Ka'bah). He said: He (the Prophet) raised his eyes towards the heaven, and laughed, and he said: May Allah curse the Jews! He said this three times. Allah declared unlawful for them the fats (of the animals which died a natural death); they sold them and they enjoyed the price they received for them. **When Allah declared eating of thing forbidden for the people, He declares it price also forbidden for them**. The version of Khalid b. 'Abd Allah al-Tahhan does not have the words "I saw". It has: "May Allah destroy the Jews!" ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/24/73))

And except with daf the majority of scholars are in consensus that music instruments are haram.
Therefore you should avoid using the income of such an instrument to feed yourself or your family. Based on this view -for instance- working in a shop that sales instruments is not a halal income and is haram.

Scholars basically offer the solution to demolish these instruments and get rid of them (islamweb #[7823](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=7823)) or in case that one has sold them -for example to non-Muslims- to "cleanse" the money by offering it to poor people not as sadaqah but as money laundry (islamweb #[277645](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=277645)).
The same my apply for comics depending on the content and verdict on the specific comcis.